# Interchanging the summation and limit with a convergence assumption

Tags: limits

Generally, we can't exchange the limit and summation. Therefore, we have $$\sum_n\lim_{k}a_{nk}\ne \lim_k \sum_n a_{nk}$$ for arbitrary $a_{nk}$. An assumption of uniform convergence is usually required. However, most counterexamples I have seen make one of the limit infinity, so I want to know that if we already know the convergence of $\lim_k \sum_n a_{nk}$ (to a finite limit) and that $\{a_{nk}\}_k$ convergences for each $n$, can we exchange the limit and summation? If still not, what if with another assumption that every $a_{nk}$ is nonnegative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let

$$
a_{nk} = 
  \begin{cases}
                                   1 & \text{if $n=k$} \\
                                   0 & \text{if $n \neq k$} \\
  \end{cases}
$$

Then $\sum_n\lim_{k}a_{nk} = \sum_n 0 = 0$ and  $\lim_k \sum_n a_{nk} = lim_k 1 = 1$.

So existence of the limits and sums isn't enough, even when $a_{nk} \geq 0$.